# undefined method `group_by_day' error

Tags: charts, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I want to use [chartkick](http://chartkick.com/) to make a line graph of all the user signup per day.

in my views I have

```
<%= line_chart User.group_by_day(:created_at).count %>
```

but it is producing that error

Comment: `group_by` is not an `ActiveRecord` method, but a Ruby method on `Enumerable`. See [this documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by)

Comment: I have a question, but in the chartkick documentation that i have given the link there it is given that way. what could be the reason it is not working?

Answer (score 4):

You need to install the groupdate gem to use the `group_by_day` method. I'll update the chartkick documentation to make this clearer.

Answer (score 0):

try this, it can work

```
<%= line_chart User.group(:created_at).count %>
```

Comment: it is drawing a straight horizontal line graph, but I want it to show the users signup record for everyday